# Return List<int> from reader.stream.listen with flutter_libserialport

Tags: flutter, dart, serial-port, modbus

I try to use flutter libserialport bull to implement Modbus RTU, however after calling the function it doesn't work.

`List<int> receivedData = await readRegisters(0xFE, 0x0000, 0x001A);`

`print('Data: $receivedData');`

When I call, nothing prints. However, it works if I use a private list and setState()!

```
await reader.stream.listen((data) { 
    print('stream : $data'); 
    setState(() { 
        response!.addAll(data); 
    }); 
}).asFuture();
```

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KNXc.png)

But after await as I called, I do want it to return for the instance variable. how I can solve it

```
Future<List<int>> readRegisters(int slaveID, int startAddress, int numberOfRegisters) async {
  // construct the Modbus Read Holding Registers command
  List<int> data = [slaveID,
    0x03,
    startAddress >> 8,
    startAddress & 0xFF,
    numberOfRegisters >> 8,
    numberOfRegisters & 0xFF  ];
  int calculatedChecksum = calculateModbusChecksum(data);
  data.add(calculatedChecksum & 0xFF);
  data.add(calculatedChecksum >> 8);
  // write the command to the serial port
  port.write(command(data));
  SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port, timeout: 1000);
  List<int> response = [];
  int bytesReceived = 0;
  while (bytesReceived < numberOfRegisters) {
    await reader.stream.listen((receivedData) {
      print('received : $receivedData');
      if (receivedData.isNotEmpty) {
        response.addAll(receivedData);
        bytesReceived += receivedData.length;
      }
    }).asFuture(response) ;
  }
  return response;
}
```

`List<int> receivedData = await readRegisters(0xFE, 0x0000, 0x001A) as List<int>; Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1),()=>  print('Data: $receivedData'));`
but they not return anything

Comment: maybe you need this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html?